# Amazon EC2 not working with user data php

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am launching a ubuntu EC2 instance with my PHP code and passing user data to it. I don't own that instance.. but they provide user level access to it.

Firstly i tried to run a particular job by passing user data, but it did not seem to work.

I made it very simple and send "touch test.txt" as user data. The instance was launched properly but the file was not created as should be i guess.

Am I missing any step? I checked that file was not created using ssh 'ing to the instance. One thing was i was not in root user at instance. Will that effect anything?

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
header("Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");
require_once '../sdk.class.php';
 // Instantiate the class
$ec2 = new AmazonEC2();
$userdata2="touch hi".".txt";
echo $userdata2;
$response = $ec2->run_instances('ami-5f21e236', 1, 1,
array('KeyName' => 'radix2'),
array('UserData' => $userdata2),
array('InstanceType' => 'm1.small')
);
var_dump($response->isOK());
?>
```

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955177/amazon-ec2-not-working-with-user-data-php

Answer (score 2):

If your UserData does not begin with `#!` it will be assumed that it is not a script.

You would be wise to read an [example of a UserData script](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/ec2-userdata) to see how you can specify a shell command in the first line of a shell script.

This is assuming that your Ubuntu instance's handling of user data is based on [ec2-run-user-data](http://ec2ubuntu.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/etc/init.d/ec2-run-user-data).